# Python List with if Condition

Tags: python

I have two lists and I want to use both in if condition together.

In case only One list this can do easily 
like if list_name : # if list a : 
for more than 2 lists this method is not working.

although we can use separately if or using len(a) like comparison. 
I am searching for simple & beautiful result.

```
a = [1,2,34]
b= [4,5,6,3]

# if a & b : # i was expecting this will work <br>
#if (a is True) & (b == True): # this all not working <br>
# if (len(a) >=1) & (len(b) >=1): # This will work but not beautiful <br>
#
    print("Not Working") # 

print("working ")
```

Comment: In Python `and` and `or` are used for joining conditions, not `&` / `&&` / `|` / `||` as in some other languages

Answer (score 0):

In Python, instead of using `&` in if statements, we use `and`.

This is how you can check both lists in the same if:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

if a and b:
    print("a and b are both valid!")
```

You can read more about Python if statements [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Inside `if-statements`, lists are automatically evaluated as `True` or `False`, depending on whether they are empty or not. Therefore, we can simply write:

```
a = [1,2,34]
b = [4,5,6,3]
if a and b:
    print('Hello World')
```

If you want to check if any list is non-empty, you can write `a or b` alternatively.

---

More information about the evaluation of `if-statements`:

[What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a very fancy way, working with lists.

Here are some very basic ones:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7]

if a and b:
    # Checks if there is something inside both lists
    # returns True if there is at least 1 value inside every list
    print("A and B not empty")

if a or b:
    # Checks if there is something at least in one list
    # returns True if there is at least 1 value inside of one list
    print("Something in A or B")
    
if a[0] == b[0]:
    # Checks the first value of both lists
    print("Value 1 of A and B are equal")

# Loops through the list of a / you can use i as index    
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
        print(f"{a[i]} is equal to {b[i]}")

# Alternative loop
for item in a:
    print(item)
```